# Camel casing hyphenated English words (e.g. re-render)

Tags: camelcasing

Typically if you're converting a string of words to [camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) you capitalise only the first letter of every word (bar the first word).

How does this apply to hyphenated words like [re-render](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/re-render)?

Something deep inside me wants it to be `rerender` or `doRerender`. And not `reRender` or `doReRender`, which just looks wrong to me.

Is this open to interpretation or is camel casing clear on this, and I'm just not seeing it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In camel-case, individual trailing words are capitalized and whitespace is dropped. Since "re-render" is a single word, and since the hyphen is a non-alpha character in the same vein as whitespace, it should be treated as a single word would normally.

```
let rerender = "The correct answer";
```

The same would be true for these other examples containing hyphenated prefixes (as opposed to hyphenated standalone words):

```
sub-zero wedding cake         : subzeroWeddingCake
co-parent advisory hose       : coparentAdvisoryHose
ongoing trans-oceanic puppies : ongoingTransoceanicPuppies
```